# Fallacy in arguments allegedly proving the irrationality and transcendence of $\pi$ and $e$ respectively

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

I'm making my way through Koblitz's *p-adic Numbers, p-adic Analysis, and Zeta-Functions*, where questions $8$ & $9$ of Exercise $1$ of Chapter $4$ have the following, apparently, fallacious arguments:

**Irrationality of $\pi$:** 
Suppose $\pi = a/b$, and let $p \neq 2$ be a prime not dividing $a$. Then
$$0 = \sin(pbπ) = \sin(pa) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(−1)^n (pa)^{2n+1}/(2n + 1)! ≡ pa\ (\text{mod}\ p^2 )$$
which is absurd, hence a contradiction.

**Transcendence of $e$:** Suppose $e$ is algebraic, then so is $e-1$.  Let $p \neq 2$ be a prime not dividing the numerators and denominators of all the coefficients of the minimal polynomials of both $e$ and $e − 1$. Then $\left\lVert e \right\rVert_p = \left\lVert e-1 \right\rVert_p = 1$. We have: 
$$1 = \left\lVert e-1 \right\rVert^p_p = \left\lVert (e-1)^p \right\rVert_p = \left\lVert e^p-1-\sum_{i=1}^{p-1}\binom{p}{i}(-e^i) \right\rVert_p$$
Since the binomial coefficients in the summation are all divisible by $p$, and since $\left\lVert -e \right\rVert_p=1$, it follows that $1 = \left\lVert e^p-1 \right\rVert_p = \left\lVert \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}p^n/n! \right\rVert_p$,
which is impossible since each summand has $\left\lVert \cdot\right\rVert_p<1$.

---

Now, in the hints given to the exercises, the hint corresponding to both these problems, i.e. the problem to locate the supposed fallacy, is given as: *Non-theorem 1 is being used*.

The so-called Non-theorem 1 is a false theorem which points out that for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ a sum of rational numbers which converges to a rational number $\left\lVert \cdot \right\rVert_p$ and also converges to a rational number in $\left\lVert \cdot \right\rVert_{\infty}$, then the rational value of the infinite sum need not be the same in both metrics.

Therefore I suspect the fallacy arises by identifying the real number $e^p$ which arises from the real limit of $\sum_{n\geq 0}p^n/n!$ to the $p-$adic number $e^p$ which arise from the $p-$adic limit of $\sum_{n\geq 0}p^n/n!$; same for $\sin(pa)$. But I don't see a concrete difference, except in abstract theory.

Does this mean we have just proven the irrationality and transcendence of the $p-$adic numbers $\pi$ and $e$, but nothing really has been said about the real numbers $\pi$ and $e$? Can someone help me understand this thoroughly?

Comment: How do you define "$p$-adic $\pi$"? s the least(?) positive(?) number for which the power series $\sum_k (-1)^{k}x^{2k+1}/(2k+1)!$ converges to $0$?

Comment: I suppose that would be an appropriate definition. But I suppose it will be vastly different from real $\pi$ due to there being a finite radius of convergence for the series, if such a number exists at all. I'm just spitballing here

Comment: You said so, if a sequence of rational numbers converges both in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}_p$, the two limits don't have to share any property in common (pick a real number and a $p$-adic number and make a sequence of rationals converging to them). Now most continuous functions we can create on $\mathbb{Z}_p$ are power series with rational coefficients, so elements of $\mathbb{Q}[[x]]$, and $\mathbb{Q}[[x]]$ embeds (and keeps its main properties) both in $\mathbb{R}[[x]]$ and $\mathbb{Q}_p[[x]]$, thus the idea of $p$-adic analysis.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: I vaguely remember that in Schikhof's *Ultrametric Calculus*, he plays around with a definition of a "$p$-adic $\pi$" somehow related to trigonometric series, but I do not have the book at hand now. It has not come up ever since, and probably was more for fun and play than for a mathematical purpose.

Comment: Defining a $p$-adic $\pi$ using a zero of the $p$-adic series $\sin x$ is impossible: on its $p$-adic disc of convergence we have $|\sin x|_p = |x|_p$, so $\sin x = 0 \Rightarrow x = 0$ and thus there is no nonzero $p$-adic solution to $\sin x = 0$.